# Experience Manager not woking on MAC browser FireFox ver 36 and safari 8.3

Tags: experience-manager, content-manager

Experience Manager not woking on MAC browser FireFox ver 36 and safari 8.3  kindly let me know if there is some hotfix for that.
I have refer the sdl doc link but they did'n provide information for Safari 8.3 ver.
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-84AA65A7-929A-4B83-BD84-DDB3649613DD

but its working fine with all browsers on windows and using sdl 2013 SP1.

**UPDATE:**
We have XPM setup on SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and it is working perfectly fine for various pages if we are accessing it through Windows Machine (On Chrome, FireFox, Safari etc.). However, if we are trying to access the XPM for inline editing the page through Mac Machine with Latest FireFox and Safari Browser - we could not get it work. With FireFox/Safari on Mac, a Blank White Page only comes when we log-in to the XPM. With Safari 7.1.4 (Which is older version), the XPM does work correctly on the Mac Machine but with Safari 8.3, it does not work fine.

We have gone through the documented list of Browser and it does suggest that it will work with Safari 7 - Is this assumption wrong that it will not work on updated browser version (8 in this case)?

**More Update:** We tried to found all logs etc. and see no error or relevant message anywhere

Comment: Have you already contact Customer Support? They'll be able to help you resolve this issue and tell you if those browsers are supported or not -- and they have a full list of the hotfixes available.

Comment: Also, if we're going to try to solve it here, you'll need to give us more details such as what exactly is not working, how far you can get, if you have any errors in your browser's JavaScript console, exactly what version of Tridion you are using (I assume 2013 SP1 from the documentation link, but even then -- do you have HR1 installed?), etc.

Comment: @Nuno: More details have been added. With Windows, it works perfectly fine in all browser; On Mac, it works fine with Safari 7.1.4 but not on Safari latest (8.x). With Firefox on Mac, it does not work as well